# Inserting specific columns from a php array into a mysql table

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I have an array containing  42 records each having 6 fields returned by  jquery post.
I am using following  method to split and organise data so that it can be inserted using an SQL insert statement.

```
$values = array();
foreach ($data as $rowValues) {
    foreach ($rowValues as $key => $rowValue) {
            }
 $values[] = "('" . implode("', '", $rowValues) . "','".$yr."','".$qtr."')";
   }

$query = "INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2, field3, filed4)  VALUES " . implode (', ', $values);
```

Here the problem is the table1 has only 4 fields and I need only 4 columns in the array but the array contains 7 columns. I want the other columns to update another table. How can I do this?

Comment: BTW: The foreach loop `foreach ($rowValues as $key => $rowValue)` is not necessary, because it's empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

You can use [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to extract the first 2 elements of array:

```
$values = array();
foreach ($data as $rowValues) {
    $values[] = "('" . implode("', '", array_slice($rowValues, 0, 2)) . "','".$yr."','".$qtr."')";
}

$query = "INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2, field3, filed4)  VALUES " . implode (', ', $values);
```

In your second query you can call

```
foreach ($data as $rowValues) {
    $values[] = "('" . implode("', '", array_slice($rowValues, 2)) ."')";
}
```

to get the remaining elements of your array.

**Solution 2:**

You can simply use the indices of the array:

```
$values = array();
foreach ($data as $rowValues) {
    $values[] = "('".$rowValues[0]."','".$rowValues[2]."','".$rowValues[5]."','".$rowValues[6]."','".$yr."','".$qtr."')";
}

$query = "INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2, field3, filed4)  VALUES " . implode (', ', $values);
```

And in your second query:

```
$values = array();
foreach ($data as $rowValues) {
    $values[] = "('".$rowValues[0]."','".$rowValues[2]."','".$rowValues[3]."','".$rowValues[4]."','".$rowValues[5]."','".$rowValues[6]."','".$yr."','".$qtr."')";
}
```

Comment: from the array $values, I want to use column s 0,2,5,6 in one query and 0,2,3,4,5,6 in second query. How array_slice can be used in this case?

Comment: @mansoondreamz I've added a secord solution that should solve your problem.